# Cordova camera allowEdit with larger targetWidth and targetHeight will crash the app

Tags: cordova

With following code, after image cropping the app crashed, but if I change the targetWidth and height to 600, it works.

Any idea?

```
navigator.camera.getPicture($scope.processImageUri, $scope.onFail, {
    quality: 25,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
    allowEdit: true,
    encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    targetWidth: 712,
    targetHeight: 712
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are trying on Android ? If yes then below is the reason.

Basically OS is trying to load the image into memory to apply the provided parameters and that causes the crash. I had read somewhere on SO that Android has this issue.

Try without providing any parameters if they are not necessary.

Comment: This worked for me, not putting anything allows me to crop the original image full size :)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that you could reduce the quality and then have a try.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
navigator.camera.getPicture($scope.processImageUri, $scope.onFail, {
    quality: 25,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: $scope.processImageUri,
    targetWidth: 712,
    targetHeight: 712
});
```